# MouseWheel event in WinForms not firing because of control properties

Tags: c#, winforms, mousewheel, visible, tabindex

I have quite a problem with the mouse wheel event. I've tried to find any sort of references to it but always found answers to different topics on the matter.

I have made a mouse-wheel event for the entire form (which is also fullscreen, but it should work regardless on where the mouse is): `MouseWheel+=ChangeLength;` (or `MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(ChangeLength);`, it doesn't matter) and put a breakpoint on the first line of it, just to see if it works.

It didn't.

I opened a blank project to test it out and surprisingly, it did! I then looked for the source of the problem and found out that only two lines in the designer make the difference between successfully firing the event, and not firing at all. The two lines were

```
 this.rater.TabIndex = 15;
 this.rater.Visible = false;
```

If any of these lines were uncommented, nothing happened when scrolling the mouse wheel, but if both were deleted or commented, it worked just fine. Using `Focus()`, clicking on the screen, changing the properties outside the designer and other known methods didn't help.

I need to add that `rater` is *not* just a regular control, and this is probably the source for this weird problem. It is a custom control called [ShapeRater](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26576/ShaperRater-A-Rating-Control). I really don't understand why and how the `Visible` and `TabIndex` properties cause it, they're completely unrelated! Also, I deleted one of the raters (which caused the problem), because the other one was fine, but once deleted, the previously OK one started causing this instead.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the issue was related to losing focus after using the arrows while in the application, so I ended up replacing the keys for that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you make it not visible, you are pushing focus to some other control (because your control loses focus and focus goes somewhere else when the control disappears). The particular control that gains focus would be dependent on the tab index values as well, since it will be something like the next or previous control that it falls to.

Notice that with a custom control, focus is not gained automatically by mouse clicks. So you will need to have a `Focus()` call in your `MouseDown` event, for example.

Besides that, in order to make a control gain mouse wheel events just by moving the mouse over it, you have to take focus in `MouseEnter`. Something like `MouseEnter += (s, e) => Focus();`. I'm not sure that that is a perfect solution, though, since I think you will be 'stealing' focus from some other control just by moving the mouse over it.

Another thing you can do which I think is much better is just handle the `MouseWheel` event of every control on the form, and then just check whether the mouse is actually within your area or not before responding to it.

Ex:

```
HandleCreated += (s, e) => {
   var maybeForm = FindForm();
   if (maybeForm == null)
      return; // or throw since you should have a form by now
   var form = maybeForm;

   MouseEventHandler mouseScrollDelegate = (s, e) => MouseScroll(e.Delta);
   foreach (var control in form.Controls.Cast<Control>())
      control.MouseWheel += mouseScrollDelegate;
};

...

void MouseScroll(int pDelta) {
   var screenMouse = Cursor.Position;
   var clientMouse = PointToClient(screenMouse);
   if (!ClientRectangle.Contains(clientMouse))
      return;

   // do something
}
```